# Multiple columns with image

Tags: html, css

i have html page that contains P tag and IMG tag.
and i want to display P tag on multiple columns surrounding the IMG tag. as in [this picture](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/585/stackoverflowcolumns.jpg/) 
using css styles and html. could you please suggest a way to achieve that.

many thanks in advance

Comment: Would the text flow have to be fluid through all the columns?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is: you can't. At least not with just a p and an img element and have it supported in all major browsers.

If you don't care about browser support, you might want to look at: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/

Comment: i want it to be supported in Safari.

Comment: i do believe the latest webkit versions have support for this, check out http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html in safari. still, having the text flow around that image is going to be a challenge :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to do it with plain HTML and CSS until browsers have support for things like [CSS3 Exclusions](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-exclusions/) or [CSS3 Positioned Floats](http://www.interoperabilitybridges.com/css3-floats/) (or whatever the result of merging them turns out to be).  No production browsers support either of these, [prototypes](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/cssregions.html) and [previews](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/info/downloads/default.html) are available but for now you'll probably need some sort of JS based solution or a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't use p tags to specify the layout for this purpose there are span and div tags, however you can put your p tags in a div and assign a background image to this div container and arrange your paragraphs around a image.

Or you can use the [960 grid system](http://960.gs/) its very nice way to create columns with CSS, here is a example for your case. It arranges the p tags in exactly the same way you described and it works in any browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* reset */
        html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,font,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;outline:0;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline;background:transparent}body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:'';content:none}:focus{outline:0}ins{text-decoration:none}del{text-decoration:line-through}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}

        /* 960 grid framework */
        .container_12{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:960px}.grid_1,.grid_2,.grid_3,.grid_4,.grid_5,.grid_6,.grid_7,.grid_8,.grid_9,.grid_10,.grid_11,.grid_12{display:inline;float:left;position:relative;margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px}.push_1,.pull_1,.push_2,.pull_2,.push_3,.pull_3,.push_4,.pull_4,.push_5,.pull_5,.push_6,.pull_6,.push_7,.pull_7,.push_8,.pull_8,.push_9,.pull_9,.push_10,.pull_10,.push_11,.pull_11,.push_12,.pull_12{position:relative}.alpha{margin-left:0}.omega{margin-right:0}.container_12 .grid_1{width:60px}.container_12 .grid_2{width:140px}.container_12 .grid_3{width:220px}.container_12 .grid_4{width:300px}.container_12 .grid_5{width:380px}.container_12 .grid_6{width:460px}.container_12 .grid_7{width:540px}.container_12 .grid_8{width:620px}.container_12 .grid_9{width:700px}.container_12 .grid_10{width:780px}.container_12 .grid_11{width:860px}.container_12 .grid_12{width:940px}.container_12 .prefix_1{padding-left:80px}.container_12 .prefix_2{padding-left:160px}.container_12 .prefix_3{padding-left:240px}.container_12 .prefix_4{padding-left:320px}.container_12 .prefix_5{padding-left:400px}.container_12 .prefix_6{padding-left:480px}.container_12 .prefix_7{padding-left:560px}.container_12 .prefix_8{padding-left:640px}.container_12 .prefix_9{padding-left:720px}.container_12 .prefix_10{padding-left:800px}.container_12 .prefix_11{padding-left:880px}.container_12 .suffix_1{padding-right:80px}.container_12 .suffix_2{padding-right:160px}.container_12 .suffix_3{padding-right:240px}.container_12 .suffix_4{padding-right:320px}.container_12 .suffix_5{padding-right:400px}.container_12 .suffix_6{padding-right:480px}.container_12 .suffix_7{padding-right:560px}.container_12 .suffix_8{padding-right:640px}.container_12 .suffix_9{padding-right:720px}.container_12 .suffix_10{padding-right:800px}.container_12 .suffix_11{padding-right:880px}.container_12 .push_1{left:80px}.container_12 .push_2{left:160px}.container_12 .push_3{left:240px}.container_12 .push_4{left:320px}.container_12 .push_5{left:400px}.container_12 .push_6{left:480px}.container_12 .push_7{left:560px}.container_12 .push_8{left:640px}.container_12 .push_9{left:720px}.container_12 .push_10{left:800px}.container_12 .push_11{left:880px}.container_12 .pull_1{left:-80px}.container_12 .pull_2{left:-160px}.container_12 .pull_3{left:-240px}.container_12 .pull_4{left:-320px}.container_12 .pull_5{left:-400px}.container_12 .pull_6{left:-480px}.container_12 .pull_7{left:-560px}.container_12 .pull_8{left:-640px}.container_12 .pull_9{left:-720px}.container_12 .pull_10{left:-800px}.container_12 .pull_11{left:-880px}.clear{clear:both;display:block;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;width:0;height:0}.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{content:'\0020';display:block;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;width:0;height:0}.clearfix:after{clear:both}.clearfix{zoom:1}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background: url(http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/9881/bbee.png) no-repeat 250px 0px;" class="container container_12 clearfix "> 
        <div class="grid_3"> 
            <p style="text-align:justify;" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_3"> 
            <p style="text-align:justify; padding-top:316px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,  eirmod tempor  sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_3"> 
             <p style="text-align:justify; padding-top:316px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor  eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_3"> 
            <p style="text-align:justify;" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this help you out :)

Comment: this is exactly why i asked the OP if the text flow has to be fluid through all the columns to which he answered Yes. I wouldve suggested something like this as it works on very static site but if its a theme of some sort or a page that you update frequently.. this just doesnt quite cut it.

Comment: Actually, a div tag is just a block level element, just like a p - only p has semantic meaning (and default margins). div and span tags are a last resort when no other tag is suitable. Seeing as all this text could be part of the same paragraph, the ideal markup would be a single p and img tag like OP was asking about. You should also avoid inline styles.